# How to install both MySQLdb and cx_Oracle on Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, mysql-python, cx-oracle

I've been trying for days to get both MySQLdb and cx_Oracle running successfully together on Mountain Lion to no avail. It appears that I can only get one or the other to run but not both. Here are my specs...

Mac OS X 10.8.2 running with (64-bit) Intel Core i7 processor

**PYTHON**:
~: python --version
Python 2.7.2

~: file `which python`
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

In .bashrc, I have set the following...
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes

**MySQL**:
~: mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for apple-darwin10.3.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
~: file `which mysql`
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

**MySQLdb**:
~: file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64

**Oracle**:
Version 10.2.0.4 (32-bit) Instant Client and SDK

I used pip to install both cx_Oracle and mysql-python (MySQLdb). Currently, I can interactively import cx_Oracle successfully, however, I get the following error when attempting to interactively import MySQLdb:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in 
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

After all the reading and troubleshooting I've done, I have learned that this error surfaces when Python and MySQL are not running on the same architecture. Since I have the 64-bit version of MySQL, I can remove the environment variable I put in .bashrc that sets the preference to the 32-bit version of Python (export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes) and the MySQLdb import works. However, I then get the following error when importing cx_Oracle:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Symbol not found: _OCIAttrGet
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so

When diving into this rabbit hole I find conflicting information about what I have set-up for cx_Oracle, what needs 32-bit architecture and what needs 64-bit tracing all the way back to my Oracle installation. I've encountered the segmentation fault error, the libclntsh.dylib error and the clang error etc. Perhaps, at this point, the information overload has sent me in circles so long that I can't clearly see the solution? But I know there has to be a way...

I thank you in advance for any assistance at all with this.

Cheers!

Comment: Ok, the appropriate architecture to use on Mountain Lion is 64-bit. I was able to resolve the "Symbol not found: _OCIAttrGet" error once Oracle pushed up a new 64-bit instant client for Mac. I subsequently got the "Symbol not found: _C_SendHTTPRequest" error which was also resolved by Oracle (see discussion here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2493519). I am now able to run both MySQLdb and cx-Oracle successfully on Mountain Lion!!

Answer (score 0):

you wrote:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

You have to install MySql 32 bits as you did for cx_Oracle and keep

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
```